# Request failed with status code 405 Nextjs 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, next.js

I'm using NextJs 14 and I get this error 405:

> GET http://localhost:3000/api/products 405 (Method Not Allowed)
> Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError

products.js

```
"use client"
import { useState } from 'react';
import Layout from '../../../components/Layout'
import axios from 'axios'

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'


export default function NewProduct() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [goToProducts, setGoToProducts] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  async function createProduct(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = { title, description, price };

    await axios.post("/api/products", data)
    setGoToProducts(true);
    router.push("/products");
  }
```

**app/api/products/route.js**

```
import { Product } from '../../../models/Product'
import { mongooseConnect } from '../../lib/mongoose'

export default async function handle(req, res) {
    const {method} = req;
    await mongooseConnect()

    if(method === 'GET') {
        res.json(await Product.find())
    }

    if(method === 'POST') {
        const {title, description, price} = req.body;
       const productDoc = await Product.create({
            title, description, price,
        })
        res.json(productDoc)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the `app router` and `pages router`. In the old days, we were building our pages using the `/pages` directory but now we can use the `/app` directory which is newer and has more functionality and of course, has different coding solutions.

In the app router, you must build your APIs inside a `route.js` file (as you did) and you must export the accepted methods as a function with UPPERCASE name like so:

###### /app/**/route.js

```
export const GET = (request) => {
    return Response.json({ text: "this is a GET request" })
}

export const POST = (request) => {
    return Response.json({ text: "this is a POST request" })
}
```

so, here I will convert your code into the app router version

###### /app/api/products/route.js

```
import { Product } from '../../../models/Product'
import { mongooseConnect } from '../../lib/mongoose'

export const GET = () => {
    await mongooseConnect()

    return Response.json(await Product.find())
}

export const POST = (request) => {
    await mongooseConnect()
    
    // you can also read as formData (https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#request-body-formdata)
    const {title, description, price} = await request.json();

    const productDoc = await Product.create({
        title, description, price,
    })

    return Response.json(productDoc)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your solution worked perfectly, and I really appreciate the time and effort you put into fixing my code :)

Comment: You're welcome @DrilonSulejmani :)